# Residues of a function calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to find residues of this function:

$$f\left( z \right) = \frac{{\sinh \left( {2z} \right)}}{{z\cosh \left( {2z} \right){{\left( {\cosh \left( z \right) + 1} \right)}^2}}}$$

My try is:

At $z=0$ then the residue is $0$

At $z = \pi i\left( {\frac{k}{2} - \frac{1}{4}} \right)$ is the point that $\cosh \left( {2z} \right)=0$ then the residue is $$ - \frac{{8i}}{{\left( {2k - 1} \right){{\left( { - 2{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^{\frac{{k\left( {k - 1} \right)}}{2}}} + \sqrt 2 } \right)}^2}\pi }}$$

At $z = \pi i\left( {2k - 1} \right)$ is the point that ${\left( {\cosh \left( z \right) + 1} \right)}^2=0$ the the residue is $$\frac{{4i}}{{{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^3}{\pi ^3}}}\left( {2 + 3{\pi ^2}{{\left( {2k - 1} \right)}^2}} \right)$$

I only choose $k$ is integers and from $k=1$. My question is these residues are correct or not. At $z = \pi i\left( {\frac{k}{2} - \frac{1}{4}} \right)$ the residue seems weird, because after calculating some values of $k$ then the sign is changing as pattern:$-,++,--,++,--...$ then I added a term to adjust this sign problem.

Thank you for reading, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5B%7Bk%2CResidue%5BSinh%5B2+z%5D%2F%28z+Cosh%5B2+z%5D+%281%2BCosh%5Bz%5D%29%5E2%29%2C+%7Bz%2CPi+I+%28k%2F2-1%2F4%29%7D%5D%7D%2C%7Bk%2C-10%2C10%7D%5D.

Comment: Are you sure about the negative in front of the $2(-1)^{k(k-1)/2}$?

Comment: @KStarGamer yes, you can try some value of $k$: $k=1$ it is $-2$, $k=2$ it is $2$, $k=3$ it is $2$, $k=4$ it is $-2$, $k=5$ it is $-2$ and so on, and it matches the link that Steven Clark posted.

Comment: @OnTheWay I disagree, check the link again. For instance, with $k=1$, the residue is $-\frac{8i}{(2+\sqrt{2})^2\pi}$, whereas your formula gives $-\frac{8i}{(-2+\sqrt{2})^2\pi}$. Happy new year too!

Comment: @KStarGamer Thank you and happy new year. My mistake, then there is no minus sign in front of $2$, the pattern is $+,--,++,--...$